# Filtering the search results from HTML DOM content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm designing a website for club management, and want to add the search filter feature to it, how can I do that with JavaScript so that I can filter search results by typing the name of club (which is the "figcaption" tag)?

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="border">
            <figure class="figure">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/437/200/200" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a>                         
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">CLUB 5</figcaption>
            </figure>
    </span>
    <span class="border">
            <figure class="figure">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/437/200/200" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a>                         
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">CLUB 6</figcaption>
            </figure>
    </span>
    <span class="border">
            <figure class="figure">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/437/200/200" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a>                         
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">CLUB 7</figcaption>
            </figure>
    </span>
    <span class="border">
            <figure class="figure">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/437/200/200" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a>                         
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">CLUB 8</figcaption>
            </figure>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery as well?

Comment: Yup @AdityaGupta

Comment: @AdityaGupta Why is jquery always the first comment question on these? You can filter perfectly fine without what is effectively an aliasing library. OP - What have you tried? We can't tell where you're stuck without this.

Comment: So, we can either hide the irrelevant results as you type in an input or show results based on what you type.

Comment: @ggdx good point. Since the latest ES6 updates, there is almost no need of jquery but some users have issue with older versions of browsers and with latest js code they end up adding transpilers like babel.

Comment: here is Jquery plugin for filter  https://isotope.metafizzy.co/  its easy to use! hope this help!

Comment: So it is kind of convenient to just go with jquery since the OP already has it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this,create a search bar and call the function.

```js
function tagsearch(caption) {
  let result = document.querySelectorAll("span")
  result.forEach((ele) => {
    if (ele.childNodes[1].childNodes[3].textContent.trim() === caption) {
      ele.style.display = "block"
    } else {
      ele.style.display = "none"
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" id="search" onchange="tagsearch(this.value)"></div>
<div class="row" id="add">
  <span class="border">
 <figure class="figure">
 <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/437/200/200" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a> 
 <figcaption class="figure-caption">CLUB 5</figcaption>
 </figure>
 </span>
  <span class="border">
 <figure class="figure">
 <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/437/200/200" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a> 
 <figcaption class="figure-caption">CLUB 6</figcaption>
 </figure>
 </span>
  <span class="border">
 <figure class="figure">
 <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/437/200/200" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a> 
 <figcaption class="figure-caption">CLUB 7</figcaption>
 </figure>
 </span>
  <span class="border">
 <figure class="figure">
 <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/437/200/200" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a> 
 <figcaption class="figure-caption">CLUB 8</figcaption>
 </figure>
 </span>
</div>



<div id="add"></div>
```

Comment: It looks so good but there's no effect on the boxes, I mean I should only have the club which I typed its name and the rest should hide (as filtering them).

Comment: Ahh,that you have to do with some css ,well wait let me update

Comment: edited my answer @BenGumaan please make adjustments accordingly

Comment: So great, and that's exactly what I wanted but there's a little problem which is "refreshing the page", if I searched for one club then I have to refresh the page to be able to do another search (filtering).

Comment: Woooooow, that was awesome my friend! 
You've really did a great job over here and you definitely deserve an up-vote for your great work.  

Happy coding!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @Shubh The problem with the solution you suggested is that it's tightly bound to the DOM structure you have. If tomorrow you decide to restructure the result item in some way, you will need to update your function accordingly. Writing test cases in such scenarios will also fail often.

Comment: @BenGumaan if you want to persist the search state, you could set the search term in the url in query params. Your app can then read the param(if exists) from the url and call the search function. This way you can even share the link with someone else.
Else you can also set the search term in the local storage. But that I will not recommend over url query since then you cannot share the link.

Comment: Its already generic  .I am already using the parent tag to reach the child ,in future if he changes the tag from figure to div it wont be a hassle for him. Otherwise whole idea of question will be waste.If you have any idea please post an answer .Thanks @AmanPandey

Comment: @AmanPandey you are moving out of the scenario,you just can't predict something non relevant from the things mentioned in the question.Thanks

Comment: @Shubh Not really. If some other approach is recommended over the one suggested and is going to help the developer maintain a good code, then why not mention it? Moreover, what I suggested is something in code quality. It may not be an exact solution to what is asked, but it will definitely help the asker better.

Comment: @Shubh as a part of your question, I would suggest to use an id(or data attr) on the figcaption and just target it. This way, restructuring of the DOM won't matter to the function logic.

Comment: The basic idea here is what the question asks ,and what the user is looking for.There are better solutions but still they will be far from the scope of this question.Using an id is better and fast but the question doesn't use any type of id in any element.@AmanPandey ,and using an id would be rather particular not general.